# How to get single value from loop generate form

Tags: php, html

Consider the following form which was created from a very simple database query and foreach loop

[image]

```
   :
    $results = $stmnt->fetachAlll();
    foreach($results as $result){
    :
    :
    echo' <input type="text" style="display:none" name="jobID[]" value="'.$result['jobID'].'" />';
    echo' <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="'.$result['amount'].'" />';
    : 
    }
```

How would I go about getting the value of JobID, which I need from the `POST_[]` request?

- $_POST['jobID'] returns an array of all the different jobID's (obviously), leaving me with not knowing which button was clicked.
- I cant try it in a `$_GET` request since all the JObID's gets printed in the URL
- I did try changing the button to an anchor link like so `<a href="#<?php echo 
  $result['jobID']">VIEW</a>` which appended the actual clicked (button) jobID to the url, however a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` did not return that part which was appended to the url after the linked was clicked...

I really don't know what else to do here? What is the usual practice in use cases such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `<button>` element to store the `jobID`, like this:

```
<button name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="<?php echo $result['jobID']; ?>">button</button>
```

Comment: NOoooooooo. How did I miss that

Comment: There are things that we forgot sometimes :-)